# How can I reference javascript across areas in MVC3 solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, javascript, projects-and-solutions

Given a solution structure like this:

```
/solution
 / client app
   / Company.Client.WebClient
     / scripts
       / libs
         / some_lib.js
     / web.config <--included for reference to indicate heirarchy
 / libraries included
 / libraries included
 / widgets
   / area1
   / area2
   / area3
     / resources
       / scripts
         / my_file.js
```

and givens include:
* MvcContrib (for Areas support) and MVC3,
* VS2010,
* no specific javascript assistive plugins installed (in case those are the answer here)

How can I go about including a `<reference>` line at the top of my `my_file.js` so that I can have intellisense for the function names in the `some_lib.js`?

I've tried `/// <reference path="../../../Company.Client.WebClient/scripts/lib/some_lib.js" />` but that doesn't quite seem to work for what I want. (ie no intellisense)

So what am I doing wrong? How does the referencing work across areas and projects like this, or does it? Is my only alternative to include a copy (wasteful? can I just use a "shortcut" in Windows to avoid copying it to every subdir I need this?) in each area?

Comment: Looks like my best solution is probably project linked files. That at least includes the intellisense I need.

Comment: Found a reasonable answer here (but I would prefer a better answer than this, because this still relies on hard-links on each dev's machine) http://www.devaffair.com/2011/01/linked-files-in-visual-studio-2010.html

Comment: Well, it looks like hard links?